# Animation randomly flickers when changing horizontal position

Tags: jquery, css

I'm writing a simple image slider but i have an issue for which i can't find a solution. Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/InflamesXL/pen/YMRLVw).

You will notice that when i append the second image to `#gallery`, the animation from left as `$(window).width()` to `0` is flickering. There's an annoying white gap between the two animated elements.

Have you seen something similar before? Is there a fix to make the animation run smoothly? So far i've tried `queue: false` and `.promise()` but nothing worked.

Comment: I think your problem stems from trying to animate the two items simultaneously - depending on when the two independent lines of code execute (if they're on different animation frames in the browser) you will have a very hard time making them join seamlessly. If you look at some existing carousels, they all get around this by putting the individual images into a single element and animating _that_. I would recommend you try that approach.

Comment: I see.. that makes sense! Thank you for your time.